# training sets and Cross Validation in pcr

Tags: r

I am working my way through the excellent An Introduction to Statistical Learning.
In one of the labs they write

```
pcr.fit<-pcr(Salary~.,data=Hitters,subset=train,scale=TRUE,validation="CV")
```

But this baffles me.  validation="CV" means it is going to do 10 fold cross validation.  I was under the impression that this means that it is going to randomly divide the set up into ten sets of roughly equal size and each will take a turn being the test set.  If so, then why do I need to specify a training set as well?  What exactly is this method doing when you specify validation="CV" AND that subset=train????

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you optimize (hyper) parameters on the train set using cross validation, then you validate them on the validation set, and then you use them in production on the test sets. Every subset of the data will prefer slightly different hyper parameters, your goal is to estimate the hyper parameters that will be close to best on all data subsets. Btw this is off topic for SO.

Comment: So when the function says validation="CV", its not really doing Cross Validation in terms of creating the model, but rather doing some sort of adjustment of hyper parameters (whatever those are).  Also - I am fairly new to Stacked Overflow - why is this question about R and data mining considered off topic?

Comment: SO is a place where you post a reproducible problem which you would like to solve with programming, as well as your code attempts to solve it, and ask a concrete question. Your question is about data science and statistics so it is better suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/. In case of `pcr` you would like to estimate how many of the principle components are best to be used for regression. This is a hyper parameter for `pcr`. You usually pick the number of principle components which minimizes the CV error.

Comment: Then you fit a model with  on all the train data and estimate its performance on the validation set.

Comment: Great - thanks for your help